# How can I edit the content in index.php?

Tags: php, templates

I want the start page to be editable from a template. At the moment I can only edit the content by directly editing the HTML.

Setup:

- Settings » Read » "Front page displays Your latest posts"
- The template that shows in the startpage is `index.php`

I want to be able to create a page edited from the Pages list that will show as the start page.

I've tried to create a new page called MyStartPage. Set its template to Startpage (`index.php`).

I've tried setting Settings » Read » Front Page displays Static page MyStartPage

I've made sure the `index.php` has The Loop that makes the calls to get Title and Content as is working in other templates.

Comment: See also [this post I recently wrote, explaining the differences](http://www.chipbennett.net/2013/09/14/home-page-and-front-page-and-templates-oh-my/)

Comment: Im reading your links but im not getting what i should do.

Comment: See also: [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Comment: Thats quite a lot altogether. Although i will read it all to understand better, is it possible you could guide me on how to fix it for now?

Comment: "*is it possible you could guide me on how to fix it for now?*" That is what I attempted to do, with the linked blog post. StackExchange sites are not really designed to handle such queries.

Comment: @ChipBennett I dont want to seem ungrateful but i wonder if we have not understood each other or i its just me that dont understand. It seems to me that you mean that the only way of helping me is to send me and ask me to read all three links you sent me. BElow you can see dot1:s answer which was exactly what i needed to know. Do you mean to say that his answer is not something Stack Exchange is designed to provide?

Comment: I don't understand why this has been marked a duplicate, it's not one (in its current state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are editing a theme or you are having a child theme, You can make your own custom template, give it a name Include header and footer in it using

```
<?php
 /**
  * Template Name: Home Page
  * 
  * Home page Layout
 */
 get_header(); ?>
 <!-- Do whateveer you want here -->
 get_footer(); ?>
```

When you create a page in backend you'll get an option to select the template for the page i.e Home Page, assign the template you just created 
[image: Home Page Template]

and set this page as home page from settings.

Comment: THANKS! It works. BUT the page i created shows in the menu as well as being the startpage. This is not ok. Can i make it unvisible from the menu except being the home?

Comment: Sorry. The page has to show ofcourse. There was already a homeapg link at the start menu but it was hardcoded so i removed it.

Answer (score -1):

Rename it to `front-page.php`. That one is loaded on the home page before attempting to load `home.php`, regardless of your "Read" settings.

Comment: Of course `index.php` is a valid template. It's the *default fallback template file* for all contexts. Also, `home.php` is only used to display the *blog posts index*, regardless of whether the blog posts index is set to display on the site front page or on another page.

Comment: I think someone hijacked the one trick pony account.

Comment: Well thank you, that's flattering :) But I do make mistakes sometimes, just like everybody else